# How do I deal with garbage values in manual string concatenation?

Tags: c

Beginner C question, For the sake of the code I'm writing, I'm ending up having to manually concatenate chars to strings with breaks inbetween, but it's spitting out garbage after it correctly concatenates the string.

I don't know how much of a nono it is, but it compiles CORRECTLY in replit, however in VS2019 its giving me garbage.

As far as I thought, malloc allocates the memory but gives an empty string, and when printed will only show what has been inserted.

Replacing stringOut[strlen(stringOut)] with stringOut[i] puts it in the beginning correctly but still prints garbage? How would I empty an allocated string so I could add chars to it manually without throwing access exceptions and printing garbage at the end?

Any thoughts?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 50
char* stringOut;
char* inString;

//========================== MAIN ============================
int main() {
  stringOut = (char*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(char));
  inString = (char*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(char));

  printf("s: ");
  scanf("%s", inString);
  //inString = "quarry/beef/foot";


  int i = 0;  
  printf("%lu ",strlen(inString)); 
  printf("%d\n",i);

  while(inString[i] != '/')
  {
    //printf("doingSTUFF");
    stringOut[strlen(stringOut)] = inString[i];
    printf("%s\n", stringOut);
    i++;
  } 

  stringOut[strlen(stringOut)] = ' ';
  printf("%s", stringOut);
}
```

Comment: This `inString = "quarry/beef/foot";` overwrites the dynamic memory address assigned to `inString` in the previous statement. You might want to use `strncpy()` here ?

Comment: That line was just for testing purposes to save me from typing tests each round, sorry.

Comment: Hint -- if you are concatenating actual strings -- there won't be any garbage values to deal with.... You know (1) `stringOut` is allocated, but uninitialized so `strlen(stringOut)` invokes *Undefined Behavior* and even if it was, (2) you would overwrite the *nul-terminating* character with every iteration in your loop with `stringOut[strlen(stringOut)] = inString[i];` and then never provide further termination?

Comment: Think about how `strlen` knows what the length is, and then review your code

Comment: also think about what happens if `inString` never has any slashes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a large number of small problems, but the primary issues are `stringOut` is allocated, but *uninitialized* so `strlen(stringOut)` invokes *Undefined Behavior* because there is no *nul-termiating* character in `stringOut` marking the end of string, and even if it was *nul-terminated*, you would overwrite the *nul-terminating* character with every iteration in your loop assigning `stringOut[strlen(stringOut)] = inString[i];` (not to mention the inefficiency in calling `strlen(stingOut)` for every iteration.

All is not lost, and your thinking isn't entirely wrong. So long as you put your accountants hat on and account for the number of characters you add to `stringOut` and add the *nul-terminating* character (`'\0'`, equivalent to plain old `0`) when you are done adding characters, all will work as it should.

Before we get there, learn why in C, there is no need to cast the return of `malloc` [Do I cast the result of malloc?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) and learn that `sizeof (char)` is defined as `1`, so there is no need to include that as a size multiplier when setting your allocation size. With that in order, your allocations would be:

```
    stringOut = malloc (SIZE);          /* allocate stringOut */
    if (stringOut == NULL) {            /* VALIDATE EVERY ALLOCATION */
        perror ("malloc-stringOut");
        return 1;
    }

    inString = malloc (SIZE);           /* allocate inString */
    if (!inString) {                    /* ditto */
        perror ("malloc-inString");
        return 1;
    }
```

When taking user input, `fgets()` is recommended Why? It consumes an entire line of input at a time given a sufficiently sized buffer, so what remains in `stdin` doesn't depend on the `scanf` *format-string*. The only caveat is all *line-oriented* input functions such as `fgets()` and POSIX `getline()` read and include the `'\n'` from input and include that in the buffer they fill. So you will need to remove the newline from `inString`. Luckily, `strcspn(string, reject)` provides a simple way to do that as it returns the number of characters in `string` not included in the `reject` list. So you can simply do:

```
    inString[strcspn (inString, "\n")] = 0;
```

Which will overwrite the `'\n'` character with the *nul-terminating* character leaving only the text input by the user. (if you need to preserve the length of `stringOut`, you can do it at the same time simply by saving the return of `strcspn` in a variable, e.g.

```
    inString[(inlen = strcspn (inString, "\n"))] = 0;
```

Which does the exact same thing, but also saves the length of `inString` in `inlen`. You can keep another variable that holds the length of `stringOut` (e.g. declared at the beginning `size_t inlen = 0, outlen = 0;`) so you can now track the length of both `inString` and `stringOut` through your program.

Now to copy from `inString` to `stringOut`, you can largely use your loop with just a few changes. The most important is you need to make sure you don't attempt to read past the end of `inString` in case there is no `'/'` contained within it (`inString[i] != 0`, or just `inString[i]`) Just add that as an additional condition in your `while` loop and you can do:

```
    /* loop while not at end and char not '/' */
    while (inString[i] && inString[i] != '/') {
        stringOut[outlen++] = inString[i];  /* copy from inString to stringOut */
        i++;
    }
```

(**note:** the use of the counter `outlen` to track the number of characters in `stringOut` rather than repeatedly calling `strlen()`)

Now `outString` IS NOT *nul-terminated* at this point. You still intend to add a `space` (`' '`) to the end according to your code, so add the `space` and then *nul-terminate* `stringOut`, e.g.

```
    stringOut[outlen++] = ' ';      /* append space, increment outlen */
    stringOut[outlen] = 0;          /* nul-terminate stringOut */
```

Now your code is done, you can output `stringOut`, and if you enclose the output in *single-quotes*, you can confirm your space is there, e.g.

```
    printf("'%s'\n", stringOut);    /* output stringOut */
```

Don't forget to free what you allocate, e.g.

```
    free (inString);        /* don't forget to free the memory you allocate */
    free (stringOut);
```

Putting it altogether, you would have:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE 50

int main (void) {

    char *stringOut;
    char *inString;
    size_t inlen = 0, outlen = 0, i = 0;    /* inlen, outlen, counter */

    stringOut = malloc (SIZE);          /* allocate stringOut */
    if (stringOut == NULL) {            /* VALIDATE EVERY ALLOCATION */
        perror ("malloc-stringOut");
        return 1;
    }

    inString = malloc (SIZE);           /* allocate inString */
    if (!inString) {                    /* ditto */
        perror ("malloc-inString");
        return 1;
    }

    printf("s: ");  /* prompt for input */
    if (fgets (inString, SIZE, stdin) == NULL) {    /* read line of input */
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stdout);
        return 0;
    }
    inString[(inlen = strcspn (inString, "\n"))] = 0;   /* get inlen, trim \n */

    /* loop while not at end and char not '/' */
    while (inString[i] && inString[i] != '/') {
        stringOut[outlen++] = inString[i];  /* copy from inString to stringOut */
        i++;
    }
    stringOut[outlen++] = ' ';      /* append space, increment outlen */
    stringOut[outlen] = 0;          /* nul-terminate stringOut */

    printf("'%s'\n", stringOut);    /* output stringOut */

    free (inString);        /* don't forget to free the memory you allocate */
    free (stringOut);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/stringout
s: quarry/beef/foot
'quarry '
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

In any code you write that dynamically allocates memory, you have 2 *responsibilities* regarding any block of memory allocated: (1) *always preserve a pointer to the starting address* for the block of memory so, (2) it can be *freed* when it is no longer needed.

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to ensure you do not attempt to access memory or write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/stringout
==9727== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==9727== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==9727== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==9727== Command: ./bin/stringout
==9727==
s: quarry/beef/foot
'quarry '
==9727==
==9727== HEAP SUMMARY:
==9727==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==9727==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 2,148 bytes allocated
==9727==
==9727== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==9727==
==9727== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==9727== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: Super in-depth answer and I learned a few new optimizations along the way, thank you.

Comment: Only difference there is I added *single-quotes within the *format specifier* `"'%s'\n"` so it would include the *single-quotes* in the output showing that the `space` had been properly appended to `stringOut` before the *nul-terminating* character was added to mark the end-of-string.

Comment: I just saw that as you answered, late night.  Thanks for the quick response though.

Comment: Good luck with your coding! We all started off at the same place. Best advice I can give is take it slow, pay attention to each byte of memory you are using when dealing with arrays, strings and allocated blocks of memory. Validate every input and allocation (you cannot use an input function correctly without **checking the return**). There is a lot to learn with C, enjoy the journey. It is a language that gives you complete low-level control over the entire machine. It's something you never really stop learning. Check the man page for each function you use - and it will fall in place.

Answer (score 1):

A few of the issues I see:

> As far as I thought, malloc allocates the memory but gives an empty string, and when printed will only show what has been inserted.

`malloc()` returns a block of memory with garbage in it. Not an "empty string." However, if you `strcpy()` something to that memory, the string will be correctly terminated and should not print the characters that were not copied over.

> inString = (char*)malloc(SIZE*sizeof(char));
>     inString = "quarry/beef/foot";

Here, you've allocated a block of memory, assigned it to `inString`, and then assigned something else to `inString`. The memory address returned by `malloc()` is now lost and you have no way to free it. Don't overwrite your allocated memory address.

> stringOut[strlen(stringOut)] = inString[i];

This is a problem. `stringOut` contains uninitialized memory. It could contain anything. So `strlen(stringOut)` will scan for the first `'\0'` character, which could be the first byte, or it could be the 10,000th byte.

> stringOut[strlen(stringOut)] = ' ';

Is this meant to terminate the string? If so, use `'\0'` instead of `' '`.

Also, don't forget to release the allocated memory with `free()`.

Comment: Thats what I mean, it's outputting garbage when i access it with strlen().  How would I empty an allocated string so i could add chars to it manually without throwing access exceptions and printing garbage at the end? 

The ' ' is just to add a whitespace at the end and "quarry/beef.." is just for testing purposes.

Comment: @Tony: I don't know how that's what you mean. You were using `strlen(stringOut)` when it makes no sense. The term *empty* suggests you have nothing but, in fact, you will always have 50 bytes here. You could write all `'\0'`s to the memory. Since this character signifies the end of the string, it will prevent garbage from being printed. But that's not really needed. All you need is to write to `stringOut[0]`, `stringOut[1]`, etc. and then write `'\0'` to the last character.